# Link that forwards a page with params jsp

Tags: html, jsp

I'm building a website for a school project. In a page i need a link to another page (profile.jsp) with params, because I need to do a query in that page. I've tried forward in `JSP` but it opens the page right away, I need to activate this with a link, or also with a button. Here I'm using windows.location but it doesn't allow me to give params as far as i now.

```html
<div class="mask_container">
<h2><%out.println(title);%></h2>
<p onClick="JavaScript:window.location='profile.jsp';"><%out.println(autor);%></p>
<img src="img/like-white.png" class="social">
<img src="img/comment-white.png" class="social">
<img src="img/download-white.png" class="social">
</div>
```

Comment: It is good to have some code you have tried for this to understand problem better.

Comment: There is no link in the code you posted. A link looks like this: `<a href="profile.jsp?param=value&otherparam=othervalue">Click here</a>`. This is plain HTML.

Comment: You can give params like this ?, and how you can get them in the other page ?

Comment: With request.getParameter().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about passing your parameter values in query string as shown below, instead of `<p>` tag put below `<a>` tag to redirect to another page

```
<a href="profile.jsp?param=<%out.println(autor);%>&otherparam=<%out.println(otherparameter);%>"><%out.println(autor);%></a>
```

You can get value of parameter on other page using `request.getParameter("param")` this will gives you parameter value.

May this will help you.

Comment: When i open the link server crashes immediately, i've copy-pasted what you've written